# Title of a fantasy trilogy where a group of children is transported to different worlds?

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, parallel-universe

In my early teens (in the late 90's) I borrowed a series of fantasy books from the public library. I remember getting annoyed when the next book in the series wasn't in, so this series has at least 3 books. The story line is still very vague to me: a group of children is transported to different worlds, I think 2 ended up in a world with highly advanced technology. Another, a boy, in a medieval type of world with swords and magic. His name was Rohan (or Rolan, Rogan, Rodan or something in that same vein that starts with an "R") and he ends up becoming The Knight of the Red Rose or has something to do with a red rose. And if I remember correctly, all these worlds are somehow connected to each other.

I originally read this series in Dutch but I'm pretty sure it's translated from English

Please help me out with finding this fantasy series. I never finished it and it has been bothering me lately.

Comment: Renald?  Then it could be _Diadem_ as Nefric suggested (it sounds _really_ close), but offhand I recall nothing about a red rose...

Comment: The Hounds of the Morrigan is a good read, but I also believe it's a standalone, and it's only about two children. Hey excellent, it looks as though @Nefric has your answer!

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69463/teenagers-taken-from-their-worlds-attracted-to-colored-gems-which-give-them-spe (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 9):

I have alo been searching for this series and just found it. It's *[Diadem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diadem_%28series%29)* by John Peel.

Answer (score 3):

Am not sure but there is a children's fantasy book called [*The Hounds of the Morrigan*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?8093) by [Pat O'Shea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_O%27Shea_%28author%29), but I'm pretty sure it is a stand-alone, not a series.

And there is [*Secret Country* trilogy](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?2530) which includes *The Secret Country* and *The Whim of the Dragon* and *The Hidden Land* by [Pamela Dean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pamela_Dean).

Am not sure about these though..what do you think?