# Teenagers taken from their worlds; attracted to colored gems which give them special powers

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel

Long ago (15 years?), I partially read a novel which I really liked. I don't remember the title or full plot of it. I would be grateful if some one can identify it from the limited plot below:

Three (or four) teenagers are taken from their worlds (or different places on earth) to a strange world full of trolls, gems, powers etc. Each one gets attracted a particular colored gem which gives them a particular power. They keep going forward battling all obstacles to achieve some vague objective.

Comment: The original is not confirmed as being a correct answer

Comment: Dup should probably go the other way since this is a series answer and that is a single title in said series.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [Diadem, Worlds of Magic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diadem_(series)) series of books by John Peel.

- 3 teenagers leave their own worlds (via portals) to travel to a central world
- Gems give them powers (levitation, communication, earth, and shape-shifting, etc)
- Trolls are a regular feature
- Battling and whatnot.
- Originally published in 1997, approx 17 years ago.

[image]