# fantasy kids book series where 3 main characters are from different worlds, have powers, and are fighting a bad guy

Tags: story-identification, childrens-novel, parallel-universe

If said bad guy uses/finds out their real names he gets control over them.

It starts off with a young male protagonist that is from a version of "our world" he discovers he can transform any matter into anything he wants. (one point he turns a bullet into a rose) . We then meet another young man who lives in a world where virtual reality has taken over and he and his friends play a game most of the time. Robots in his house take care of everything. We then meet a girl who is from a middle age type world and is a bad ass. I don't recall much about her.

I hope this is enough plot to help!

Comment: I edited out the [tag:fantasy-genre] tag, since that’s for questions about the history and conventions of the genre itself.

Comment: Diadem: Worlds of Magic. Answered [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/69463/51379).

Comment: Please don't edit back in tags that were specifically removed because they weren't used correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I think this may be a series called [Diadem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diadem_(series)), the first book of which is "[The Book of Names](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738706175)", by John Peel.

The series does start out with three protagonists, one from a high-tech world with people all but living in VR - that would be Pixel,  whose talent is finding solutions, one from a middle ages warrior culture type world - Renald, who had foresight and had been using a male disguise to learn to fight, and one from a world very similar to ours - Score, who can change matter, or turn one thing into another.  The bullet into a rose trick sounds very familiar.

One of the plots is indeed that real names can be used to attack or control people - the protagonists bend that rule twice, once by leaning on nicknames (or screen names) instead of rarely-used formal names, and I think once the reverse, when dealing with a foe that had heard about the first attack's failure.