# 90s (or earlier) book series: 4 teenagers from different worlds discover they used to be the rulers, and turned themselves young to escape something

Tags: story-identification, books

I was reading it in the late 90s as a young teen. Scifi/fantasy type.

I think there were 4 teenagers from different worlds that all got lumped together somehow. They had some level of magic and they started traveling to get to the inner worlds. As they got there, their magic got more powerful.

At some point they found out that they used to be the rulers and they turned themselves young again to escape something....

Comment: Diadem: Worlds of Magic.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/182872/51379

Comment: Yep, that's it!