# Book series about three teens who have to collect gemstones in different realms

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, wizards

I don’t remember much about the series, but I think there were three teens who were transported from world to world to collect a gemstone in each world to stop some evil wizard person. There may or may not have been animals involved that helped, but I cannot remember if it was actually a part of the series. Each gemstone had a specific color and might have been associated with an element or power of some sort.

I think it’s an older series, as I read it back in the early 2010’s and it was old then. Can’t remember the title or author.

Comment: Do you recall roughly how many books there were in the series, or how many you read? Also, you recall if the teenagers were boys, girls, or a mix?

Comment: This sounds like the Diadem series by John Peel, as discussed in several previous questions e.g. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/69463/teenagers-taken-from-their-worlds-attracted-to-colored-gems-which-give-them-spe/69464

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly a series called [Deltora Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deltora_Quest_(book_series)) by Emily Rodda. It was originally published around 2000.

There are three main characters (I can't quite remember if they were all teens) but they were going between 7 distinct regions within their world looking for gems from the Deltora belt or something similar to use against the Shadow Lord.

I think there was a Diamond, Emerald, Lapis Lazuli, Opal, Ruby, Amethyst, and I think the last gem was a Topaz.